# Fixed size SurfaceView - Android

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, preview, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to use a SurfaceView to preview the camera in portrait mode. I'm initializing the camera correctly, and everything is working fine.
However, my SurfaceView has a fixed size, something like this:

```
<SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp" />
```

and I can't get it to preview with the correct ratio, the preview is always stretched.

I'm calculating the preview camera resolution with the following method:

```
private Point findBestPreviewSizeValue(Camera.Parameters parameters, Point screenResolution, Rect surfaceFrame) {

// Sort by size, descending
List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes = new ArrayList<Camera.Size>(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes());
Collections.sort(supportedPreviewSizes, new Comparator<Camera.Size>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Camera.Size a, Camera.Size b) {
    int aPixels = a.height * a.width;
    int bPixels = b.height * b.width;
    if (bPixels < aPixels) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (bPixels > aPixels) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
});

int w;
int h;

if(surfaceFrame == null) {
  w = screenResolution.x;
  h = screenResolution.y;
} else {
  w = surfaceFrame.width();
  h = surfaceFrame.height();
}

Log.i(TAG, "Surface resolution is " + new Point(w, h));

final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

if (supportedPreviewSizes == null) return null;

Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

int targetHeight = h;

for (Camera.Size size : supportedPreviewSizes) {
  double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
  if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
  if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
    optimalSize = size;
    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
  }
}

if (optimalSize == null) {
  minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
  for (Camera.Size size : supportedPreviewSizes) {
    if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
      optimalSize = size;
      minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
    }
  }
}

Point p = new Point(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
Log.i(TAG, "Camera resolution is "+ p.toString());
return p;}
```

Is there a way to show the camera preview with the correct aspect ratio without modifying the size of the SurfaceView?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your SurfaceView tries to stretch to full screen width, and thus it may not match any of supported preview resolutions of your camera. In such case, would you prefer to adjust the height, or have margins on left and right, or maybe crop the preview to display exactly `100%`x`250dp`?

Comment: You can wrap your SurfaceView in a custom FrameLayout to adjust the aspect ratio. See e.g. AspectFrameLayout in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/AspectFrameLayout.java). The camera preview will be scaled to match the View size.

Comment: @AlexCohn yes, in fact that's exactly what happens (it doesn't matches any of the supported preview resolutions). How can I crop the preview?

Comment: @fadden I've already tried that, but it's not the result that I've expected, the preview is very small, and that doesn't serve my purposes

Comment: To crop a SurfaceView, simply put it in a layout and partially cover by some other views.

Comment: @David if the preview is "very small", you've set the size incorrectly. The preview should extend to the edges of the screen in one direction, and be cropped the other direction. Are you trying to show the entire preview frame with a correct aspect ratio, or cut off the edges of the preview content, so the preview fills the display?

Comment: @David iam facing the same problem right searched a lot .! i want to use the fixed surface view in my app but the camera preview is stretched.:-(